# Building Docker Containers in VSTS

Tags: docker, azure-devops

I am trying to set up a private Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS) build agent to build docker images. I have followed the instructions in the following article http://normalian.hatenablog.com/entry/2018/03/23/044202 but am still getting the following error

```
[error]Unhandled: Failed which: Not found docker: null
```

I have installed docker-compose following the link https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/#install-compose. Now I am completely stuck? Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to restart the build agent after the `docker-compose` installation? It might be required to pick up the recent environmental changes...

Comment: Yes, unfortunately this made no difference. The install step for the docker-compose.exe is simply copying the exe to the docker directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have not installed Docker CE  on the agent machine.

Please install [Docker Community Edition for Windows](https://store.docker.com/editions/community/docker-ce-desktop-windows) on your agent machine, and then setup VSTS private agent.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks - that is exactly what I did in the end and it started to work. What is worth noting is that when rebooting the server it asks you if you want to enable the hyper-v feature in Windows. I specifically declined this as I didn't require the service to be running in order to use the build tools.

Thanks